# react-bootstrap spinner does not render

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

Attempting to use react-boostrap Spinner in a React component. A typical scenario where the component displays a Spinner until response data is received from a backend API call.

There is a flag - `isDataFetched` which is initially false and gets set in `componentDidMount()` only when the response data is received. Conditional rendering allows disabling the data table until response is received and instead tried displaying Spinner. However, the spinner simply does not show.

Bumped `react-bootstrap` version to `v1.14.0` after realizing that Spinner was introduced only later. The issue did not resolve though.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Spinner } from 'react-bootstrap';
import DataService from '../service/DataService';


class ProjectListComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {    
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            tech: 'cb',
            formState: {
                isDataFetched: false
            }
        }
        this.refreshProjects = this.refreshProjects.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.refreshProjects();
    }

    refreshProjects(tech) {
        
        if (!tech) {
            tech = 'cb';
        } 
       

        
        DataService.findProjectsByTech(tech)
            .then(
                response => {
                    
                    this.setState({
                        formState: {
                            ...this.state.formState,
                            isDataFetched: true
                        },
                        tech: tech,
                        projects: response.data
                    });
                }
            ).catch(exp => {
              //some exception handling
            });
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                
                <h4>Projects List</h4>
                
                {this.state.formState.isDataFetched && this.state.formState.isDataFetched === false && (
                        
                    <Spinner animation="border" role="status">
                        <span className="sr-only">Loading...</span>
                    </Spinner>
                    
                )}
                {this.state.formState.isDataFetched && this.state.formState.isDataFetched === true && (
                        <p>Data Table</p>  
                )}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default ProjectListComponent
```

Comment: theres a lot of errors in your code, your only setting the flag after the response and this condition `this.state.formState.isDataFetched && this.state.formState.isDataFetched === false &&` can never pass, il post an answer

Answer (score 1):

Fixing the logic in the conditional rendering part as pointed by @roy-b helped achieve the desired output.

```js
{!this.state.formState.isDataFetched && (
  <Spinner animation="border" role="status">
    <span className="sr-only">Loading...</span>
  </Spinner>
                        
)}

{this.state.formState.isDataFetched && (
  <p>Data Table</p>  
 )}
```

Answer (score 0):

Theres a lot of errors in your code, your only setting the flag after the response and this condition `this.state.formState.isDataFetched && this.state.formState.isDataFetched === false &&` can never pass

try this:

```
   class ProjectListComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {    
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            tech: 'cb',
            formState: {
                isDataFetched: false
            }
        }
        this.refreshProjects = this.refreshProjects.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.refreshProjects();
    }

    refreshProjects(tech) {
        
        if (!tech) {
            tech = 'cb';
        } 
       
        this.setState({
                        formState: {
                            ...this.state.formState,
                            isDataFetched: true
                        })
        
        DataService.findProjectsByTech(tech)
            .then(
                response => {
                    
                    this.setState({
                        tech: tech,
                        projects: response.data
                    });
                }
            ).catch(exp => {
              //some exception handling
            });

            this.setState({
                        formState: {
                            ...this.state.formState,
                            isDataFetched: false
                        })
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                
                <h4>Projects List</h4>
                
                {this.state.formState.isDataFetched &&                         
                    <Spinner animation="border" role="status">
                        <span className="sr-only">Loading...</span>
                    </Spinner>
                    
                )}
                {!this.state.formState.isDataFetched && this.state.projects && (
                        <p>Data Table</p>  
                )}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default ProjectListComponent
```

ALSO, I recommend changing the flag to a more accurate name like **isDataFatching**

Comment: Agree with the conditional rendering part. I somehow missed evaluating it correctly. However, I don't think that setting the flag outside the Promise `then` method will guarantee that the UI gets rendered only after the response is received. I'll answer the question.

Comment: @ark202 you want to show the spinner while fetching the data so before the request sent you change it to show spinner and after the response (either response or error) you remove the spinner